# How to set the Content-Type header for a RestRequest?

Tags: rest, c#-4.0, restsharp

I have a web service in a RESTful web server (java) which consumes media of type ***MULTIPART_FORM_DATA*** and produces *APPLICATION_JSON*. I'm working on a REST client (C#) and using this web service. I'm using RestSharp as the REST client. My code goes as follows:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("addDelivery", Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("sessionId", this.sessionId);
request.AddParameter("deliveryTo", DeliveryTo);
request.AddParameter("deliveryName", DeliveryName);

if (fileList.Count() > 0) // If fileList is not empty
{
    // Adds all the files to request
    foreach (MyFile myFile in fileList)
    {
        request.AddFile(myFile.fileName, myFile.filePath);
    }
}
```

It works fine as long as I provide a file(s). If a file isn't provided (`fileList` is empty) I'm getting **HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type**. I think as I'm not providing any file the `Content-Type` is automatically changed to some type other than `multipart/form-data`. But the web service consumes ***MULTIPART_FORM_DATA*** and maybe that's why getting this error. I've tried adding the following code segment but getting the same error:

```
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

Note that this action(sending request without files) can be performed successfully from other clients (java, ios)

Comment: Have you inspected the request before you pass it to the client.execute method? If you do not set a content-type header, form-url-encode is the default for any POST method

Comment: Yes, If no file is provided the `Content-Type` is set as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. But to work with the web service I need to keep it as `multipart/form-data` even if I don't provide any file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want [this](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/RestSharp/RestSharp/IHttp/P/AlwaysMultipartFormData):

```
request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Since RestSharp has assumed Content-Type application/x-www.form-urlencode when you don't add any files you need to apply that yourself. This should solve your problem.

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("addDelivery", Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("sessionId", this.sessionId);
request.AddParameter("deliveryTo", DeliveryTo);
request.AddParameter("deliveryName", DeliveryName);

if (fileList.Count() > 0) // If fileList is not empty
{
    // Adds all the files to request
    foreach (MyFile myFile in fileList)
    {
        request.AddFile(myFile.fileName, myFile.filePath);
    }
}
else // fileList.Count() is 0 or fileList is null
{
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
}
```

Comment: I've tried it already and mentioned it as well. Sadly it doesn't work. The same error occurs.

Comment: Can you provide an expanded version of your sample, with service and client?

Comment: I have having the same issue.  request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); doesn't do anything in my code too, It appears RestRequest object simply disregards it or reset it just prior to making the call