# Can't set multipart/related ContentType in RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I need to use multipart/related ContentType. I do like this:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.AddParameter("Content-Type", "multipart/related", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
```

But I always get

**multipart/form-data**

In the Http request

Is there any way to force multipart/related?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258659/how-to-set-the-content-type-header-for-a-restrequest

Answer (score 1):

I was plagued by this for a few days and was diligently searching for a solution. My solution comes from a few different posts over a few days so I apologize for not linking to them. Below is a sample Function to perform a multipart/related POST with json body and base64 pdf string as the file.

```
public static void PostBase64PdfHttpClient(string recordID, string docName, string pdfB64)
    {
        string url = $"baseURL";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var myBoundary = "------------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_";
        string auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"UN:PW"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {auth}");

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{url}/api-endpoint");
        request.Headers.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        MultipartContent mpContent = new MultipartContent("related", myBoundary);
        mpContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", $"multipart/related; boundary={myBoundary}");

        dynamic jObj = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject(); jObj.ID = recordID; jObj.Name = docName;
        var jsonSerializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObj, jsonSerializeSettings);

        mpContent.Add(new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        mpContent.Add(new StringContent(pdfB64, Encoding.UTF8, "application/pdf"));

        request.Content = mpContent;

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking forever for this.. I was stuck on trying to use MultipartFormDataContent without creating a HttpRequestMessage myself. Just a small problem with your code: You dont need to add to the Content-Type as it will already have been set to MultiPart/related and your boundary. So you actually end up with a Content-Type header that says the same thing twice which broke my request!

Answer (score 0):

According to their [documentation](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest):

> If you have files, RestSharp will send a multipart/form-data request.
>   Your Parameters will be part of this request in the form

Don't think there is a way around that.

Comment: Yes, this is what I discovered by reading the source code on github

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this does work today if you do as follows:

```
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/related")
request.AddJsonBody(…);
request.AddFile(file.Name, file.FullName, "application/pdf");
```

It does append the boundary and manage it appropriately; however, I am still looking into the feasibility of adjusting the header for each body part, as it doesn't seem directly supported.